# Export Android compiler Warning to text file

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, compiler-warnings

I want to write all the compiler warnings in a text file.
Once we build it, we can see warnings in Build Output as seen in screenshot.
Is the file already available?

[image]

Comment: Can you show screenshot which warnings do yu want to export and what to do with them next?

Comment: @Andrey Screenshot attached